# cannot define a static array with variable length?

Tags: c

I am trying to create a static array where the length of the array could differ. I am doing this so that i can return the array from a function without using pointers.

I have tried:

```c
void arrExample1(int size){
    #define len size
    satic int arr[len];
}
```

```c
void arrExample2(int size){
    enum { len = size };
    static int arr[len];
}
```

Neither of these have worked and I am at a loss of what I should do next. Can I get some advice or pointed in the correct direction?

Comment: "_I am doing this so that i can return the array from a function without using pointers._": That's not typically a good idea. Allocate memory with `malloc` instead (and `free` it later) or let the caller pass a pointer to an array of the correct size to the function. The latter approach allows the caller to choose where the memory resides.

Comment: That's just the thing: the length of an array with static storage duration *cannot* differ.  The lifetime of such an array is the entire run of the program, so not only can it not change, but the size must be known at compile time.

Comment: “Static” means, just as a plain English word, “lacking in movement, action, or change.” You should not expect static objects to vary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can only define it dynamicly.
Here is how, in case u need it:
[Dynamicly creating an array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bjn5A.png)